# insert data to database and display it into a table jquery onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, insert, display

is there anything wrong with my jquery code here?
i want to do insert data and display data using termo_i.php. the script for inserting data is running but the script for displaying the database value failed i think. i would appreciated when you give me an example.

```js
$(document).on('click','#ok',function(e) {

      if ($('#no').val() == '') {
                     alert('Kolom No Tolong Di Isi dan Tidak Boleh Sama Dimulai Dari 1');
                 } else {
        var data = $("#form_input").serialize();  
        $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
            url: "../php/termo_i.php",
            success: function(data){
        var list = JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $('#tanggal').val((list[i]['s_tanggal']));
    $('#nama').val((list[i]['silo']));
    var tr = "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor1']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor2']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor3']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor4']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor5']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor6']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor7']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor8']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor9']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor10']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor11']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor12']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['ambien']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['average']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['deffiasi']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['status']+"</td>";

    tr += "</tr>";

    $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
  }
  return false;
}
});
                     }

    clearInput();
});
$("#form_input").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {
       $('#s1').val('');
       $('#s2').val('');
       $('#s3').val('');
       $('#s4').val('');
       $('#s5').val('');
       $('#s6').val('');
       $('#s7').val('');
       $('#s8').val('');
       $('#s9').val('');
       $('#s10').val('');
       $('#s11').val('');
       $('#s12').val('');
       $('#amb').val('35.0');
       $('#avr').val('');
       $('#deff').val('');
       $('#sts').val('');
    });


}
```

```html
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "silo");


// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $no= $_POST['no'];
    $tanggal= $_POST['datepicker'];
    $silo= $_POST['silo'];
    $sensor1= $_POST['s1'];
    $sensor2= $_POST['s2'];
    $sensor3= $_POST['s3'];
    $sensor4= $_POST['s4'];
    $sensor5= $_POST['s5'];
    $sensor6= $_POST['s6'];
    $sensor7= $_POST['s7'];
    $sensor8= $_POST['s8'];
    $sensor9= $_POST['s9'];
    $sensor10= $_POST['s10'];
    $sensor11= $_POST['s11'];
    $sensor12= $_POST['s12'];
    $amb= $_POST['amb'];
    $avr= $_POST['avr'];
    $deff= $_POST['deff'];
    $sts= $_POST['sts'];
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO temp1 (no, tanggal, silo, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5, sensor6, sensor7, sensor8, sensor9, sensor10, sensor11, sensor12, ambien, average, deffiasi, status) VALUES ('$no','$tanggal','$silo','$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3','$sensor4','$sensor5','$sensor6','$sensor7','$sensor8','$sensor9','$sensor10','$sensor11','$sensor12','$amb','$avr','$deff','$sts')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "Records inserted failed ";
}
// Data for Titik1
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM temp1");
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Your echo in insert is breaking the echo json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store your msg in your row array like this

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "silo");

$rows = array();

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$no= $_POST['no'];
$tanggal= $_POST['datepicker'];
$silo= $_POST['silo'];
$sensor1= $_POST['s1'];
$sensor2= $_POST['s2'];
$sensor3= $_POST['s3'];
$sensor4= $_POST['s4'];
$sensor5= $_POST['s5'];
$sensor6= $_POST['s6'];
$sensor7= $_POST['s7'];
$sensor8= $_POST['s8'];
$sensor9= $_POST['s9'];
$sensor10= $_POST['s10'];
$sensor11= $_POST['s11'];
$sensor12= $_POST['s12'];
$amb= $_POST['amb'];
$avr= $_POST['avr'];
$deff= $_POST['deff'];
$sts= $_POST['sts'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO temp1 (no, tanggal, silo, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5, sensor6, sensor7, sensor8, sensor9, sensor10, sensor11, sensor12, ambien, average, deffiasi, status) VALUES ('$no','$tanggal','$silo','$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3','$sensor4','$sensor5','$sensor6','$sensor7','$sensor8','$sensor9','$sensor10','$sensor11','$sensor12','$amb','$avr','$deff','$sts')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
$rows['msg']="Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
$rows['msg']="Records inserted failed ";
}

$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM temp1");


while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Like what? The array in php or in my jquery code dude?

Comment: @JackHenaldy sorry for not add code now please try code.

Comment: @JackHenaldy your php array rows store you success or error message in array like $rows['msg']="success" or $rows['msg']="error" i am insert in code like this.